# Fancy indexing to matrix operations

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, numpy-ndarray

Suppose:

```
A=np.array([1,2,0,-4])

B=np.array([1,1,1,1])

C=np.array([1,2,3,4])
```

With fancy indexing I can assign a scalar value to C wherever A > 0.

```
C[A > 0]= 1
```

But is there anyway to get something like C = B/A wherever A > 0 while preserving the original values of C for A <= 0 with fancy indexing ? If I try something like

```
C[A > 0] =  B/A
```

I get an error like:

```
<input>:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 4 input values to the 2      output values where the mask is true
```

I can get the result with a for loop or making copies of A & C where :

```
D = np.copy(A)
E = np.copy(C) 
D[ D <= 0]= 1
E=B/A
E[A <=0] = C
```

or set C=Run(A,B) where

```
def Run(A,B):
    C=np.zeros(A.shape[0],A.shape[1])
    for i in range(len(A)):
        if A[i] != O: 
            C[i] = A[i]/B[i]
        else:
            C[i] = C[i]
```

But i was just wondering if there was a more direct way to do it without adding so many steps if i am looping millions of times.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can index the operands: `C[A > 0] =  B[A > 0] / A[A > 0]`.  You might want to compute `A > 0` once, and reuse it, e.g.

```
mask = A > 0
C[mask] =  B[mask] / A[mask]
```

A more efficient alternative is to use the `where` parameter of `np.divide` or `np.floor_divide`.  For example,

```
In [19]: A = np.array([1, 2, 0, -4])                                            

In [20]: B = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1])

In [21]: C = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [22]: np.floor_divide(B, A, where=A > 0, out=C)
Out[22]: array([1, 0, 3, 4])

In [23]: C        
Out[23]: array([1, 0, 3, 4])
```

I had to use `floor_divide` because all the arrays are integer arrays, and `numpy.divide` creates a floating point array, so that function will complain about the type mismatch if the `out` array is an integer array.  If you want a floating point result, `C` should be an array of floating point values:

```
In [24]: C = np.array([1., 2., 3., 4.])

In [25]: np.divide(B, A, where=A > 0, out=C)
Out[25]: array([1. , 0.5, 3. , 4. ])

In [26]: C
Out[26]: array([1. , 0.5, 3. , 4. ])
```